# navigating through list when starting with a middle index

Tags: jquery

I am in need of a starting point for my current problem.

I have a list of elements resulting from a jquery call. The item that was selected can be either first, last or the middle, first and last is no issue as i either iterate up or down the list, struggling to figure out how to start in the middle and work my way from that position.

So

```
<ul>
 <li id="1">one</li>
 <li id="2">two</li>
 <li id="3">three</li>
 <li id="4">four</li>
 <li id="5">five</li>
</ul>
```

If i start at three lets say and i want to change each one of the values to something else

```
<ul>
 <li id="1">two</li>
 <li id="2">three</li>
 <li id="3">four</li>
 <li id="4">five</li>
 <li id="5">six</li>
</ul>
```

Hopefully I have managed to explain enough of my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution will be using the while loop.With this code you can start from any point index.

```
               var currentIndex = 3 ; // some value
               var startIndex = currentIndex;
                // move up if possible
               while(startIndex <= 0)
               {
                  startIndex--;
               }

               // 2nd part
               startIndex = currentIndex;

              while(startIndex < maxCount)
               {
                   startIndex++;
               }
```

Comment: thanks was looking at doing the same. can get the index from the selected query then move up and down from there.